# Android - MediaRecorder - Application lost the surface

Tags: android, video-capture

I first try to create the SurfaceView with:

```
SurfaceView sv = new SurfaceView(context);
// Get a surface
surfaceHolder = sv.getHolder();
// tells Android that this surface will have its data constantly
// replaced
surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);        
wm.addView(sv, params);
```

Then try to prepare recorder:

```
try {
    camera.unlock();

    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
                .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO,
                appName).toString());

    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());

    mediaRecorder.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    releaseMediaRecorder();
    Log.d(TAG,
        "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: "
                        + e.getMessage());
    return false;
} catch (IOException e) {
    releaseMediaRecorder();
    Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());

    return false;
}

return true;
```

But I get an error "Application lost the surface" despite that I can see that preview is working. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

The possible reason is that Surface instance will be completely created only after MediaRecorder instance does.

The solution is to place the SurfaceView initialization (the first fragment of code in question) to onStart() in activity. It will guarantee that creation of Surface with all corresponding callbacks will be finished before MediaRecorder initialisation.

Comment: Yes, I confirm this behavior. First, you have to initialize the camera with camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder) and camera.startPreview(). And after the camera image is visible in the preview surface you call camera.unlock() and new MediaRecorder().setCamera(camera).